# How good is this class pattern with private variables?

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, prototype, private

I read in several posts that class methods should be added to the `prototype` rather than written in the function body, e.g. for inheritance:

```js
function MyClass() {
    var privateVar = 5;
}
MyClass.prototype.getVar = function() {
    return privateVar; // doesn't work!
}
```

But to access variables, they have to be made public:

```js
function MyClass() {
    //Some IDEs know this should be private because of the _underscore.
    this._privateVar = 5;
}
MyClass.prototype.getVar = function() {
    return this._privateVar; // works
}
```

However, I had an idea how to make class members private, but it's a bit more effort. Here I demonstrate it with an Encryption class that shifts characters:

```js
;"use strict";

var EncryptionClass = function() {
    var priv = []; //The private namespaces of EncryptionClass instances
    
    function EncryptionClass() {
        //Create new private namespace for this instance:
        var p = {};
        this.privI = priv.push(p) - 1;
        
        //Private class member:
        p.password = (Math.random() * 200) | 0; // integer between 0 and 200
    }
    
    EncryptionClass.prototype.encrypt = function (str) {
        //Fetch private namespace
        var p = priv[this.privI];
        
        var res = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
            res += String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i) + p.password);
        
        return res;
    };
    
    return EncryptionClass;
}();

//Test:
var encryption = new EncryptionClass();
alert("Hello World\n" + encryption.encrypt("Hello World"));
```

Here, the `privI` variable is global, but `priv` is in a closure, so the private namespaces can not be accessed from outside.

**I would like to know what you think about this pattern, and what disadvantages/drawbacks it has.** For example, I'm not sure if this could result in a **memory leak**.

Comment: It is generally considered inelegant to add members to the global namespace. You can instead return `EncryptionClass` from the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll edit it.

Comment: This may be better suited for code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd question why it needs to be oh so private in the first place. What exactly are you gaining from this bending over backwards?

Comment: @deceze It hides implementation details. This is called **encapsulation**. Other languages like Java support it by default. And in some cases it might be important for data security.

Comment: Agreed. I don't see any advantages from all the back bending either

Comment: A naming convention like `_privateVar` is usually enough to "hide implementation details"; it doesn't have to be "physically inaccessible" to be "hidden", you simply mustn't write code that touches others' privates. "In some cases it's important for data security" sounds extremely hand-wavey to me.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if this could result in a memory leak.

Yes indeed. It will result in a horrible memory leak - regardless when the `EncryptionClass` instances are garbage collected, those private namespace objects never will.

This makes all discussion of the other advantages/disadvantages futile.